# MIssing or stray quote when uploading CSV file (CSV::MalformedCSVError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, import, controller

I am trying to upload the following CSV file:

```
1,Order,"{\"customer_name\":\"Jack\",\"customer_address\":\"Trade St.\",\"status\":\"unpaid\"}"
2,Order,"{\"customer_name\":\"Sam\",\"customer_address\":\"Gecko St.\",\"status\":\"unpaid\"}"
1,Product,"{\"name\":\"Laptop\",\"price\":2100,\"stock_levels\":29}"
1,Order,"{\"status\":\"paid\",\"ship_date\":\"2017-01-18\",\"shipping_provider\":\"DHL\"}"
2,Product,"{\"name\":\"Microphones\",\"price\":160,\"stock_levels\":1500}"
1,Invoice,"{\"order_id\":7,\"product_ids\":[1,5,3],\"status\":\"unpaid\",\"total\":2500}"
1,Invoice,"{\"status\":\"paid\"}"
```

When I try to upload it, I get the following error: 
CSV::MalformedCSVError in CustomersController#import

The third line here specifically is highlighted:

```
class Customer < ApplicationRecord
  def self.import(file)
    CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true) do |row|
      Customer.create! row.to_hash
    end
  end
```

Here's the import I made in the controller as well:

```
  def import
    Customer.import(params[:file])
    redirect_to customer_path, notice: "Customer Added Successfully"
  end
```

I'm aware this issue could be from a quote syntax error, but I don't see anything wrong with the quotes I have on the first line. Everything seems in order and I believe everything else is correct, so I'm a bit stumped. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

I replaced `\"` with `'` and it worked:

```
1,Order,"{'customer_name':'Jack','customer_address':'Trade St.','status':'unpaid'}"
```

I agree it's bit weird. Hope solution will work for you.

Comment: If you are creating the CSV you could encode the JSON in base64 so you don't have to change \" to '

Comment: Wow, that was it. Getting a new, but different error now, that says unknown attribute, but I will work on that for a bit. I didn't see any reason why the \" wouldn't work before, but thanks so much.